# How do I add an outdoor GFCI outlet to an existing indoor 2 wire outlet with no ground?

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

Indoor outlet does not have a ground wire but the outdoor outlet does.

Comment: Not true, replacement of existing two-wire receptacles with a GFCI and no equipment ground is allowed under 406.4(D). You just can't add a new receptacle without a ground.

Comment: If you do that, though, you need to label the GFCI as having NO GROUND - at which point doesn't it effectively just become another receptacle?

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo GFCIs have no requirement for ground whatsoever, in any way at all.   If you had a largely ungrounded house, fitting GFCIs would not only be possible, it would be smart.  Push come to shove, it might even be safer than a house which had perfect grounds but no GFCIs.  With the GFCIs you would have fault protection, and that is a big deal esp. with outdoor receptacles.

Comment: My bad then - retracted

Answer (score 2):

If you were replacing an existing two-wire receptacle you could do that with a GFCI without an equipment ground.

However since you are adding a new receptacle, I believe that is covered by this article of the National Electrical Code:

> **250.130(C) Nongrounding Receptacle Replacement or Branch Circuit Extensions.** The equipment grounding conductor of a grounding-type receptacle or a branch-circuit extension shall be permitted to be connected to any of the following:
>
> (1) Any accessible point on the grounding electrode system as described in 250.50
>
> (2) Any accessible point on the grounding electrode conductor
>
> (3) The equipment grounding terminal bar within the enclosure where the branch circuit for the receptacle or branch circuit originates
>
> (4) For grounded systems, the grounded service conductor within the service equipment enclosure
>
> (5) For ungrounded systems, the grounding terminal bar within the service equipment enclosure

So, basically you have to run an Equipment Ground back the main panel unless you can attach to the grounding electrode or grounding electrode conductor along the way.

Good luck and stay safe!

Answer (score 1):

It's a 2-step process here.

First, replace the indoor ungrounded receptacle with a GFCI receptacle.  Do not use the LOAD terminals of the GFCI.  Label the receptacle cover "No Equipment Ground".   This is totally legal, and actually a pretty good idea.   Get that working and tested and all OK.

Second (and here's the dodgy part) extend the circuit to your outdoor receptacle, **coming off the `LOAD` terminals of the GFCI**.  Use a plain receptacle, not a GFCI type.  Mark the outdoor receptacle "GFCI Protected" and "No Equipment Ground". This is dodgy because you may not legally be allowed to add a receptacle without fitting a ground wire.  However, this will be safe.

I recommend using a NEMA 5 (grounded) receptacle and the sticker that says "No Equipment Ground".  If you use a NEMA 1 receptacle and no sticker, people will mistakenly think they can get ground from the cover plate screw.  Also, NEMA 1 receptacles are an invitation for people to break ground pins off equipment and extension cords.

Comment: the interior outlet with no ground is wired LOAD so what is my next step?

Comment: Take the interior receptacle off of LOAD or it will not work. Put those wires on LINE. Wire the outdoor receptacle on LOAD.

Comment: *"an invitation for people to break ground pins off"* ... <shudder>

Comment: Retired Master Electrician the reason for asking the question of "the interior outlet with no ground is wired LOAD so what is my next step?" this is the original wiring in the house. I found it odd one set of wires to this outlet and wired to LOAD to boot. I assume this was common in the early 1960's Denver metro area-Colorado.